# Pendrive does not show up in Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux, usb, mount, linux-mint

H have a Linux Mint 15 - Cinnamon edition on my computer.
Today I booted up my Linux (I use dual boot) and downloaded the ISO for Mint 16. It worked.
But since I logged in today, my USB, SD, and built-in storage do not show up in the left side of my file manager (the default one).

I want to use Unetbootin to copy the ISO to my USB stick, but it says: " You must first mount the USB drive /dev/sdb1 to a mountpoint." Although all of the storage systems work fine on Windows, and on Linux, gparted can recognise that it is there. Please help.

Comment: Well, a quickfix: Check your drive's letter with `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal). From a terminal again, mount the drive. "sudo mkdir /mnt/apendrive && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/apendrive" That would make a new folder under /mnt, and mount the drive there.